# Momentum and energy of photon

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, energy-conservation, redshift

Does the momentum and energy of photon change when it travels from distant galaxies through the Space?

Comment: It does. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift

Comment: OP is not talking about photons climbing out of a gravitational well.

Comment: @josephh I  noted "when it travels from distant galaxies " , distant galaxies *are* gravitational wells.

Comment: Clearly the OP is referring to universal expansion redshift _not_ gravitational redshift. Cheers.

Comment: This question is missing context: Where did you get the claim that momentum and energy of a photon *don't* change from?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/667740/311056 From here

Answer (score 2):

A photon traveling through intergalactic distances in space *does* lose energy and momentum, due to spacetime expansion (universal expansion). This is termed [cosmological redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift#Expansion_of_space) where the wavelength at which the light is originally emitted becomes lengthened as it travels through an expanding universe, meaning the photon loses energy.

The energy of a photon is given by $$E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$$ where $h$ is Planck’s constant, $c$ is the speed of light, and $\lambda$ is the photon’s wavelength. So if $\lambda$ increases, energy decreases.

The momentum of photon is $$p=\frac{E}{c}=\frac{h}{\lambda}$$ which means it also loses momentum due to universal expansion.

Here we assume the photon moves through empty space and does not interact (and redshift) with gravitational fields of massive objects. That is, energy loss is due to universal expansion only (the photon "interacts" with the expanding universe only).

Comment: Where does it loses the Energy and momentum to? And if it does why can we still se it!?

Comment: Hi A.M. That's actually a question that has been debated many times. Energy conservation in cosmological models is far from clear. In fact, energy conservation in General Relativity has always been problematic. Have a look at [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13577/photons-in-expanding-space-how-is-energy-conserved) question and the answers/links therein. Cheers.

Comment: There is gravitational redshift, too. Is cosmological redshift not some Doppler effect? What you describe sounds much more exciting than the life saving automobiles (the formula refer to gravitational, not cosmological redshift, the latter is Doppler effect, the former isn't).

Comment: @PeterBernhard Gravitational redshift occurs when electromagnetic waves travel out of a gravitational well. Cosmological redshift occurs due to expansion of the universe. Note that Doppler shifting usually refers to relative motion between source and observer. Which formulas are you referring to? I have listed two equations that express the energy and momentum of photons.

Comment: Wikipedia you link to says "To derive the redshift effect, use the geodesic equation for a light wave, which is ... ", followed by some formula that  does  not correspond to the ones you listed. - Admittingly, at time above,   I  was wrong about cosmological redshift being considered as a pure Doppler effect. They seem to consider cosmological redshift as some kind of gravitational redshift, to tell from the formula I wasn't able to past and copy in (from the Wikipage linked to). In my mind, that formula you did not list does not refer  to gravitational redshift nor Doppler redshift.

Comment: @PeterBernhard Right. As per my last comment, those equations above are general and describe the energy and momentum of quantum particles. They have nothing to do with redshift as such. Cheers.